# can't install basemap package in linux

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to install `basemap` in linux system using `pip install --user basemap`. But I am getting the following error.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement basemap-data<2.0,>1.2 (from basemap) (from versions: 1.3.0a1, 1.3.0b1)
No matching distribution found for basemap-data<2.0,>1.2 (from basemap)
```

I don't want to install this using conda. Does anyone have any solution? I am using Python2.7.15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because at that time only `basemap` v1.3.0b1 was available (a beta release). When trying to resolve its dependencies, `basemap-data` v1.3.0b1 was not found because `pip` did not count the beta release of `basemap-data` as a valid candidate.

This is now solved with the stable release v1.3.0 of `basemap`. Since you are using GNU/Linux and Python 2.7.15, you can install it with `pip` as usual (precompiled binary wheels are available):

```sh
python -m pip install basemap
```

Note that `basemap` does not install the high resolution datasets by default. In case you need them, you need to install them with `pip` too:

```sh
python -m pip install basemap-data-hires
```

Disclaimer: I am the current `basemap` maintainer.